# Problems with USB microphone

Tags: linux, arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio, skype

My USB mic in webcam in Skype not working (cam works fine). I use Arch Linux with alsa. I set up pulseaudio but then I removed it because it is not stable.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfdff4000 irq 16
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfdafc000 irq 27
 2 [Camera         ]: USB-Audio - USB2.0 Web Camera
                      Vimicro Corp. USB2.0 Web Camera at usb-0000:00:13.2-3, high speed
```

Here's alsamixer screenshot:

[image: [alsamixer screenshot]]

I checked in Capture Input source as Rear Mic / Front Mic and I hear only noise ( What is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `alsamixer` screen shot shows information for the wrong card, use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select the USB camera, and <kbd>F4</kbd> to show capture controls.

You also have to select the capture input from the correct card. Very likely "Rear Mic / Front Mic" are the mic inputs of your main audio card, and as no microphones are connected, of course you hear noise.

Use `arecord -L` to list available capture devices, your camera should show up as something like `dsnoop:CARD=Camera,DEV=0`. Select this capture interface in your application. The `dsnoop` in front means several applications can use it to record at the same time, possibly you'll also `hw:2,0` or something similar in your application. This uses the hardware directly, only one application can record.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. The solution was found on Archlinux forum:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191392

Basically, run

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
sudo pacman -U orc-0.4.22-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

which downgrades orc, which is a package used by pulseaudio. It worked for me.